# How to create a clickable area on the whole block view?

Tags: 8, views, blocks

I created a block view that shows *Article* nodes. The display format is *Grid bootstrap*.

How can I create a clickable area on the whole block view?

I want the whole block to be clickable and redirect users to /node/nid.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS and custom template structure...

Markup:

```
<div class="views-row">
    // Your various markup.
    {{ content }}
    // Link contains no text and is absolute positioned to cover the entire markup area.
    <a class="link" href="{{ link }}" title="Link to {{ print node title here }}"></a>
    // The span can be absolutely positioned as well so it is on top of the link.
    <span class="flag">This is a flag</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.views-row {
    position: relative;
}

a.link {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

span.flag {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

With this approach, you will avoid having a link that contains a lot of text and markup that makes no sense to browsers and screen readers.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this approach yesterday. It works but the link area is well displayed on forefox, but out of the block on chrome. How did you go about doing that with a view? Do you have some capture? The advantage of this method is that it is possible to use the tokens of the view.

Comment: I updated my answer just a bit. If you are having browser support issues try to ensure that the order of cascade in the dom is what you need. The flag comes last, the link before that... Views also loves to print out a million divs, these might interfere... And maybe clear chrome cache just in case.

Comment: Just a cursory glance I am seeing a difference in the render... The first div "lavender" contains the field with the class "views-teaser-link", but the subsequent divs (mini-skewers, make a repellent, etc...) do not. So for some reason that field is not being rendered on all items you are including in your view. Does that field exist on on all content types you are including in this view? Or is available if you are using display modes? Looks like the differences lay with the content types "see the recipe" and "join the discussion"

Comment: so he missed views-row relative can you take a look and tell me if I have not forgotten anything? I temporarily added a background-color to see the link.

Comment: The others also work, it's just that I applied it to only one type of "article" content

Comment: Success?! Ok great! Remember to clear cache, I am still seeing the same markup I was for my previous comment.

Comment: at the top of this page https://www.s1biose.com/produit/savon-artisanal-bio-la-cannelle i have a green block. I created a link but I can not put it on the whole block. An idea ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Javascript to do this. To do this you would have to provide a block twig override file, and wrap the entire output with an `<a href...` tag.

Note that if you do that, the other links won't work, like Flag, since you can't have anchors within anchors.

Here is an example from a project last year:

```
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}{{ title_suffix }}

    <a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': NODE_ID_VAR}) }}">

    {% if block_content.field_sidebar_image is not empty %}
      {{ content.field_sidebar_image }}
    {% endif %}

    <div class="c-sidebar-promo__content">
      <div class="c-sidebar-promo__header">
        {% if block_content.field_title_image is not empty %}
          {{ content.field_title_image }}
        {% endif %}

        <h4 class="c-sidebar-promo__title">{{ label }}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="c-sidebar-promo__description">
        <p>{{ content.field_sidebar_description }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    </a>

  {{ content|without('field_sidebar_image', 'field_sidebar_description', 'field_sidebar_link', 'field_title_image') }}
</div>
```

This makes the entire block output clickable to the provided link destination.

Edit: Updated the example with how to generate a node link with Twig.

Comment: Thank you you answered at the same time as my question with twig https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258641/how-to-create-a-link-around-a-view-block

Comment: If I put a z-index on top of the block link, it will not work ?

Comment: Why would you stack links on links? The question says how to make the whole block linked to the node.

Comment: yes I want to put the whole block and if possible keep the flag on top

Comment: I updated my question "Additional attributes" can it be useful to create the link ?

Answer (score 0):

For a view with a fields show format :

- add the content id field
- override the templates for view fields in your theme, in my case views-view-fields--seminary--block-2.html.twig

  < a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': fields.nid.content|striptags|trim}) }}">
  //Some fields